# Is there a way to display a CMS username in a profile?

Tags: drupal, profile, user-account

We are using Drupal 7.

We have a makeshift membership directory using profiles.  That works great.  But our members often forget their usernames, and we have some systems where members can uniquely identify other members by their usernames.  So it would be nice to display their user name in the membership directory.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you using Views at all for the directory, or just Civi's profiles?

Comment: Just Civi profiles.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in Drupal via Views where you can easily join the civi contact to their drupal user record and hence show both the civi 'name' and the user 'name'.

(mostly adding this for completeness as it 'is' an Answer, and SE likes answers ;-) )